# Determine whether the set of vectors is a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials $f\left(t\right)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $3$.

I am trying to show that whether all polynomials $a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$ with $\left(a+b\right)\left(c+d\right)=0$ is a linear subspace of $V$.

I understand we need to show that the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication to prove its a linear subspace.

So far I have let $p=a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$ with $\left(a+b\right)\left(c+d\right)=0$ and $q=e+ft+gt^2+ht^3$ with $\left(e+f\right)\left(g+h\right)$.

I then have $p+q=\left(a+e\right)+\left(b+f\right)t+\left(c+g\right)t^2+\left(d+h\right)t^3$

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try something like $1-t+t^2+t^3$ and $1+t+t^2-t^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the polynomial $p+q=\left(a+e\right)+\left(b+f\right)t+\left(c+g\right)t^2+\left(d+h\right)t^3$, you now have that $a' = a+e, b' = b+f, c' = c + g,$ and $d' = d+ h$.
When you multiply out

$$
(a' + b')(c'+d')
$$

the terms $(a+b)(c+d)$ and $(e+f)(g+h)$ will show up both equaling $0$, however, there will also be many other terms, like $ag, ah, \dots$, a hint that most likely the product will not equal $0$. Instead of dealing directly with that complicated product, going off of Mikhail's answer, try to find two simple polynomials $p$ and $q$ that satisfy the condition such that $p + q$ does not. For example, taking $p = t^2$ and $q = 1$ will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether the set $U$ of all $(a,b,c,d)\in{\mathbb R}^4$ satisfying $$(a+b)(c+d)=0$$ forms a subspace of ${\mathbb R}^4$. The condition looks so strange that we are lead to the conjecture that the answer is no. Therefore we try to find a counterexample. If some ${\bf x}=(a,b,c,d)$ satisfies the condition then so does any $\lambda{\bf x}$. Trying with ${\bf x}=(1,-1,c,d)\in U$ and ${\bf y}=(a,b,1,-1)\in U$ however shows that we may choose $a=b=c=d=1$ to produce ${\bf x}+{\bf y}=(2,0,2,0)\notin U$.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with the most general equation it may be helpful to restrict to a simplest case when the equation is still nonlinear, for example by setting $b=d=0$.  Then you are left with $ac=0$, clearly a nonlinear equation.  Now try to show that the set of polynomials $a+ct^2$ satisfying $ac=0$ (i.e., either $a=0$ or $c=0$) is not a vector subspace.

Answer (score 0):

your subset  contains 1 (with a = 1, and  b = c = d = 0)
cotains also t ( a = c = d = 0 and b = 1)  as well,
contains t ^ 2, and contains t ^ 3 (same argument). So to show that this subset is a vector space we must show that any polynomial of degree at most 3 is written in the given form; or the identification of two polynomial ensures that this it is not fair. So this is not a vector space.

Comment: my "or " in the texte  is french,  so remplace "or"  with  "but" I am sorry